# Jetpack compose not showing bitmap image for very high quality image

Tags: android, android-compose-textfield, coil, android-image-capture, android-compose-image

When image bitmap is low quality I am able to load and display the image with `coil` but when image bitmap is very high quality the screen doesn't show anything and pressing back lets to crash the app.
I tried bitmap instead the painter but same result happens. Could you Please tell me what might be the problem ?

`code`

```
Image(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
       painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = viewModel.bitmapImage),
       contentDescription = null
     )
```

`Crash log`

````
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 28010
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.notifyLayerIsDirty$ui_release(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1043)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayer.setInvalidated(ViewLayer.android.kt:72)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ViewLayer.destroy(ViewLayer.android.kt:295)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.onLayerBlockUpdated(NodeCoordinator.kt:431)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(NodeCoordinator.kt:332)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place(Placeable.kt:442)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1$1$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:645)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1$1$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:644)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:202)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:450)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:92)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeAt-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:427)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place(Placeable.kt:442)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place$default(Placeable.kt:211)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentMeasurePolicy$measure$3.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:712)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentMeasurePolicy$measure$3.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:704)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:275)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$layoutChildren$1$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:77)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.layoutChildren(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:267)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:930)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:35)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:445)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:450)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate$placeOuterCoordinator$1.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:92)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.placeOuterCoordinator-f8xVGno(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:444)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.replace(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:465)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.replace$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:818)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:445)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:330)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:774)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:216)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:999)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20340)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19122)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19122)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19122)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4350)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19122)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3456)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3256)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2610)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1533)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7455)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:953)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:765)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:697)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:939)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6711)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
    ```
````

Comment: "pressing back lets to crash the app" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the app, along with any messages Coil might be logging. The Coil documentation indicates that [`rememberAsyncImagePainter()` is not for everyone](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#asyncimagepainter) -- perhaps [using `AsyncImage()`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#asyncimage) would be a better choice in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved the problem by reducing the image size